# Algorithm to transform one set of numbers to another with optimization

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

We need to transform a set of integers `A` to another set of integers `B` such that the sum of squares of the elements of `B` is equal to a certain given value `M`.

Since there can be multiple such transformations, we need to find the one in which the sum of the square of the difference between the corresponding elements of `A` and `B` is minimum.

**Input:**

- A set of non-negative integers `A` = {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>}
- A non-negative integer `M`

Output:

- A set of numbers `B` = {b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub> ... b<sub>n</sub>}, such that:

  - *sum<sub>i=1->n</sub>[ b<sub>i</sub> ^ 2 ]* = `M`
  - *sum<sub>i=1->n</sub>[ (a<sub>i</sub>-b<sub>i</sub>) ^ 2 ]* = `S` is minimized.
- The minimum sum `S`.

Comment: The last condition will make this really hard to do and even harder to prove (at least that is my feeling from the first look at it).  As you want the  whole difference sum to be minimal then many smaller differences would be better then few bigger ones as count grows linear and difference grows quadratic. Do you really need the second condition to be true or it is enough to be "close" ? If not (no proof needed then) simple optimization similar to CCD (cyclic coordinate descent) would do ... Do you have sample input? what range are the values (nonnegative?) ...

Comment: There are some questions. I presume since you refer as sets the elements are unique. Is set A sorted? What is the correlation between set A and set B? Are we going to chose the elements of set B among set A? If A and B sets have equal length (as indicated) then there can be no correlation among the sets and B will only be correlated to M. Then the order of set B's elements will directly effect the result and I am afraid along with each solution (set B) set a permutation of it has to be checked against the minimal sum of square of the differences as well.

Comment: @Spektre The input values are all non-negative. I've updated the question to reflect that. Unfortunately, I don't have any sample inputs; although if you want I can upload some by creating a brute-force program.

Comment: @Redu The input set need not be sorted, and there is no correlation between `A` and `B`.

Comment: @Anmol Do you have any further clarifications to the problem? If not, are either of these answers acceptable?

Comment: None of the answers give a solution to the problem. One answer says that it is impossible to solve, but I disagree.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of math.

*Sum* (a<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *Sum* (a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2 a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) = *Sum* a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2 *Sum* a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub> + *Sum* b<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

The first term is constant; the last one is M (also constant), so you are seeking to maximize

*Sum* a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub>

with the restriction *Sum* b<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> = M.

In other words, you need a hyperplane normal to a vector A = { a<sub>i</sub> }, tangent to a hypersphere with a radius *sqrt*(M). Such hyperplane passes through a point where the normal line intersects with the sphere. This point is *fA* with |*fA*| = *sqrt*(M):

*f* = *sqrt*(M)/*sqrt*(*Sum* a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)

The solution to your problem is

b<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i</sub> * *sqrt*(M)/*sqrt*(*Sum* a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)

Comment: scaling only suffice the first condition but how can you be sure there is not a better solution also leading to `M` but with smaller difference sum ?

Comment: @Spektre I can. Think geometrically. We are looking to the point at a hypersphere closest to the endpoint of a vector. I could come to the same result analytically, via Lagrange multipliers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), but in this case geometrical intuition seems to be simpler.

Comment: @user58697 I did not understand a word of what you wrote. Could you explain in simpler terms, or redirect me to some study material so that I'd be able to understand your answer ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is a bit of a problem here. The output vector must contain integers, but the formula you gave can result in fractional numbers. How to remedy this ?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The answers so far, including the one below, map A to a set of real numbers instead of integers. As far as I can tell there is no general fix for this because there are many values of M for which there is no integer vector satisfying the constraint. Ex: M = 2. There is no vector of integers the sum of whose squares is 2. Even if M is a sum of squares, it is a sum of a certain number of squares, so even M = 4 has no solution if A has 3 or more non-zero components. As such, there is no general mapping that satisfies the problem as stated.

Here is the version that allows B to be a vector of reals:

The answer by @user58697 is quite elegant. Here is a restatement that is, perhaps, more intuitive for those of us less used to thinking with hyper geometry:

Treat A and B as vectors. Then start the same way: sum(a<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = sum(a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) - 2sum(a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub>) + sum(b<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)

The first term is the magnitude of the vector A squared just as the last term is the magnitude of vector B squared. Both are constant so only the middle term can change. That means we want to maximize sum(a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>i</sub>) which is exactly the dot product of A and B (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The dot product of two vectors is maximized when the angle between them is 0, which is to say when they are co-directional (that is they point in the same direction).

This means that the unit vector forms of A and B must be the same. That is:
a<sub>i</sub>/|A| = b<sub>i</sub>/|B|. Solve this for b<sub>i</sub>: b<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i</sub> * |B| / |A|

But |B| is just sqrt(M) and A is sqrt(sum(a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)). So, just like in user58697's version:

b<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i</sub> * sqrt(M) / sqrt(sum(a<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>))

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Should I accept this as an answer, as it was the first one that succeeded in making me understand the solution, or the other one as that was the first to technically contain the solution ?

Comment: There is a bit of a problem here. The output vector must contain integers, but the formula you gave can result in fractional numbers. How to remedy this ?

Comment: Haha! That's a noob mistake...always write down what you're solving for...have to think about this one a bit more.